# Convergence or divergence of a sequence

Tags: calculus

Determine the convergence or divergence of

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}$$

I was trying to use the propriety $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$, maybe I can write this

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n \ \times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times(n-3)\cdots2\ \times \ 1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n \ \times\sqrt[n]{(n-1)}\times\sqrt[n]{(n-2)}\times\sqrt[n]{(n-3)}\cdots\sqrt[n]{2}\ \times \sqrt[n] 1= 1\times1\times1\times1\times1\times\cdots1\times1\times1=1$

Am I right?

Comment: Try to take the natural logarithm of each term of the sequence.  Examine the convergence of those.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You have the inequality backwards.

Comment: Doh! Lost a lot of sleep due to the election fiasco. @ava

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I purposely didn’t watch the returns last night. It would have been a slow motion miasma lasting hours  vs. the quick and rude shock I got this morning. Who's @ava?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $n$ is even, then $n!> (n/2)^{n/2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a factorial somewhere in a problem of limits, I automatically thing about [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac n e \right)^n$$ $$\sqrt[n]{n!}\sim (2 \pi n)^{\frac 1{2n}}\,\frac n e $$ So, for large $n$ $$\sqrt[n]{n!}\sim \frac n e $$